# How do you use got node module with node createWriteStream to download an image with electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

I have looked at a couple of other answers, but they did not help me.

node version 16.8.0
windows 10
"got": "11.8.2",
electron 14.0.0

Here is what I am trying.  The code below does download the file but createWriteStream throws error --

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError [ERR_INVALID_RETURN_VALUE]: Expected
> AsyncIterable or Promise to be returned from the "destination"
> function but got type undefined.

Code in my render file

```
module.exports.getTile = async function (url, outputFilePath) {
    const pipeline = promisify(stream.pipeline);

    await pipeline(
        got.stream(url),
        fs.createWriteStream(outputFilePath),
        (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Pipeline failed', err);
            } else {
                console.log('Pipeline succeeded');
            }
        });


    stream.finished(input, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Stream failed', err);
        } else {
            console.log('Stream is done reading');
        }
    });
};
```

I call the function with `await getTile(url, tilePath);`

Comment: Omit the completion handler (3. argument) when using a promisified pipeline() function

Comment: thanks if you want to put it as an answer I will mark it correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stream.pipeline(...streams, callback)` accepts *n* stream middlewares and a final callback argument as per [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_streams_callback).

`util.promisify(...args, callback)` accepts a function with an error-first callback and wraps it into an async function that throw on errors. ([docs](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original))

When the two are combined, `util.promisify` will consume the final callback argument in `stream.pipeline`, and return an async function that only accept stream middlewares: `util.promisify(stream.pipeline)(...streams)`.

Consequently, the following snippet

```js
await pipeline(
        got.stream(url),
        fs.createWriteStream(outputFilePath),
        (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Pipeline failed', err);
            } else {
                console.log('Pipeline succeeded');
            }
        });
```

Should be rewritten as:

```js
try {
  await pipeline(
    got.stream(url),
    fs.createWriteStream(outputFilePath)
  )
  console.log('Pipeline succeeded');
}
catch( error ){
  console.error('Pipeline failed', err);
}
```

Comment: You could also use the `.then()` and `.catch()` alternatives like this:

<pre><code>
    pipeline(
        got.stream(url),
        fs.createWriteStream(outputFilePath)
    ).then(() => {
        console.log('Pipeline succeeded');
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error('Pipeline failed', err);
    });
</code></pre>